# What's the name of the installer progress bar

Tags: android

If you go to Google Play and install an app you get a progress bar as it downloads and installs.

While that is happening, if you swish your finger down from the top of the screen (outside your app) you see another progress bar which eventually completes and changes itself to a pretty picture and "App Successfully installed". The notification then sits there until it is cleared by the user.

What is this called? And where is the documentation for it?

Comment: Marked down and no comment - coward. I apologies for not knowing the correct terms, which is why I'm asking. How do you know what to search for, if you don't know what to search for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress in notifications is done the same way it is done everywhere else on Android, using the ProgressBar widget.
The widget used in the Play notifications is using style Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal .

Of course, this is documented on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html)

I found [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/) which seems to showcase the same kind of functionality ...

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get it to work from this link and accept if I can.